# How to select the first element inside a td using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is what my html looks like:

```
<table border="1">
        <th></th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="btn1"><input type="button" value="btn2"></td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="btn1"><input type="button" value="btn2"></td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>HTML</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="btn1"><input type="button" value="btn2"></td>
            <td>45</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Based on this structure of the html, which is being emitted by asp.net I want to add class on the first btn only of each row.

I tried using this but what happen is that even the second button of the td is also being selected:

```
 $(function () {

            $t = $('#GridView1 td').children().addClass('first');


        })
```

Sir/Ma'am your answers would be of great help. Thank you++

Comment: You have invalid markup: `<th>` elements should be inside `<tr>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to select the first input in the first `td` in each tr. Try:

```
$("#GridView1 tr > td:nth-child(1) > input:nth-child(1)").addClass("first");
```

Of course, the less strict but more concise

```
$("#GridView1 input:nth-child(1)").addClass("first");
```

could also be used, but this assumes you aren't using inputs anywhere else in your table.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EKFkt/1/)

Comment: the class is only being applied on the first row, but the remaning tr td is not affected. But the solution is very near from solving :)

Comment: @randelramirez1 That can't be right, I didn't apply the `:first` selector to the `tr`s, I applied it to the `td`s. What about the second one?

Comment: the second one has the same effect as the 1st.

Comment: correction to my 1st statement what I meant was the td input inside the 1st row.

Comment: @randelramirez1 Correct, I've fixed my answer.

Comment: Another alternative: `$("input:first",$("#GridView1 tr"))`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tr > td:first").addClass('first');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tr > td").addClass('first');
```